# Angular routing sendings to correct URL but nothing changes

Tags: html, angular

I have set up my routing.
the navigate sends me to the correct URL when I login to my App but nothing changes.

Instead of changing from login screen to the defulat "my-comp works".
it stays on the same page.

i havn't found any answer to this online

**this is the login Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginDetailes } from 'src/app/Entities/LoginDetailes';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
public loggedin:boolean;
public loggedClient:string;
public errormessage:string;
public loginDetailes = new LoginDetailes();
  constructor(private loginservice:LoginService,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.loggedin=false;
  }
public onLogin():void{
  const observable=this.loginservice.login(this.loginDetailes);
  observable.subscribe((returnedLoginDetailes:LoginDetailes)=>{
    alert("Welcome "+this.loginDetailes.name);
    this.loggedin=true;

  if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="ADMIN"){
    this.router.navigate(['/adminLay']);
  }
  else if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="COMPANY"){
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  else if(this.loginDetailes.clientType=="CUSTOMER"){
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }else{
    alert("Wrong Login Detailes");  
  }

  }, err => {
  this.errormessage=err.console.error("Wrong Detailes please Check Again!");
  alert(this.errormessage);
}
  )}}
```

**this is the login HTML:**

```
<table>
    <label>Name</label>
  <tr>
    <input [(ngModel)]="loginDetailes.name" class="enjoy-css" type="text" placeholder="ID" >
  </tr>
  <label>Password</label>
  <tr>
    <input [(ngModel)]="loginDetailes.password" class="enjoy-css" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <select [(ngModel)]="loginDetailes.clientType">
     <option  value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
     <option  value="COMPANY">COMPANY</option>
     <option  value="CUSTOMER">CUSTOMER</option>
   </select>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <input  type="button" (click)="onLogin()" value="Login" Router>

  </tr>
</table>
```

**router module:**

```
const routes:Routes=[
{path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
{path: '',component:LoginComponent},
{path:'crtComp',component:CreateCompanyComponent},
{path:'adminLay',component:AdminLayoutComponent}
]
@NgModule({
exports:[RouterModule],
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

i dont have  anywhere

Comment: Please can you provide a code so we can help at this case, without code I think we don't know how to start to help you.

Comment: @Spritzig i edited the code to the post

Comment: post the code where you have define ur router-outlet and also the route module

Comment: edited the router module to the question and i didnt use router-outler

Comment: @EliKnaffo Did you defined the `your-comp` at the `app.module.ts` to the `entryComponents` ?

Comment: @Spritzig the component is defined inside the app.module.ts

Comment: {path: '',component:LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'} not sure it will work but try this

Comment: also make sure you have router-outlet in ur html?

Comment: @WasifKhalil didnt work as my problem is not about the URL is about the login page staying instead of seeing the "adminLyt" page. the URL changes to the correct one but it stays on the same page. Also i dont know where i should put the <router-outlet> in my HTML as im new to angular

Comment: it can be caused because of pathMatch

Comment: okay wait let me show u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router module

```
export const appRoutes: BaseRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'login', component: BlankTemplateComponent, isTemplate: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'

      }
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

App Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }),

  ],
  entryComponents: [BlockUiTemplateComponent],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Last step ur html file should have `<router-outlet>`

```
<div id="loading-wrapper" *ngIf="loading">
    <div id="loading-text">LOADING</div>
    <div id="loading-content"></div>
</div>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

router-outlet is where your html will be displayed when u redirect

the above code is not same as yours, it was just to give you example to setup routes

Comment: https://medium.com/coding-blocks/angular-6-routing-made-easy-part-1-f347c8a85947 this seems like a good guide

Comment: ok so the fix for my problem was making a layout-components that only has <router-outlet> tag in the HTML. and making it the bootstrap component.